# Rudin Problem 2.17: compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know my solution is wrong but have no idea why.
Here is the statement of the part of the problem.

> Let *E* be the set of all x ∈ [0, 1] whose decimal expansion contains only the digits 4 and 7. ... Is *E* compact?

My wrong solution is here:

> We construct open sets $G_i$ as follows: $G_1$ = (0.4, 0.7), $G_2$ = (0.4, 0.77), $G_3$ = (0.4, 0.777), ... so that $\bigcup_i^\infty G_i$ is an open cover of *E*. However, no finite subcover of this covers *E*. Thus, *E* is not compact.

Again, I know this is wrong and E is, in fact, compact. But I think I have provided a counterexample. Could anyone tell me a flaw in this pseudo-proof?

Comment: @coffeemath not sure what you mean, $0.7$ is a decimal whose first digit is $7$ but it belongs to every $G_k$ with $k\geq 2$. The problem with this argument is it misses $0.4$, and it misses $\frac{7}{9}=0.777\dots$

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think you are right about missing $0.777\dots$ (and that is the answer on this question). But missing $0.4$ does not matter, does it? It is not an element of $E$.

Comment: Do you allow finite and infinite expansions?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Shouldn't we read it in this context as $0.400\dots$ then (so also containing zero's)?

Comment: @drhab oh yes, you're probably right

Comment: @peek-a-boo Well, Paul Frost asked about this. The question should be made clearer by the OP to take away any doubts.

Comment: @drhab but the question is literally phrased like this in baby Rudin, so OP (most likely) being a student won't be able to intuit Rudin's intended meaning, so it's not really OP's 'fault'

Comment: @peek-a-boo Agreed.

Comment: @drhab It seems that Rudin only considers infinite decimal expansions. See section 1.22 "Decimals".

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you. I suspected that but could not check myself (do not have the book at my disposal). If not then things would become ambiguous. For instance we could write $0.4$ (element of $E$) also as $0.3999\dots$ (not element of $E$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint.
Let
$$
K_1=[.4,.5]\cup [.7,.8] \\
K_2=[.44,.45]\cup [.47,.48]\cup [.74,.75]\cup [.77,.78] \\
K_3=[.444,.445]\cup [.447,.448]\cup [.474,.475]\cup [.477,.478]\cup
[.744,.745]\cup [.747,.748]\cup [.774,.475]\cup [.777,.778]
$$
etc.

Then $K_j$s are compact and so is $\bigcap K_j$.

Comment: The OP wants to know what's wrong with his/her counterexample, so this does not answer the question.